# com.google.ads.AdView failed to instantiate error

Tags: android, xml, listview, layout

I tried alot of things but couldn't manage to do it. The app always crashes when I try. I want the ad to be at the bottom of the screen and not cover the last listview item when scrolled to the bottom.

Here is my xml that works without the ads. EDIT: Here is the latest code. I am getting com.google.ads.AdView failed to instantiate error. My ads work in a different layout but for this layout they are not showing.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_weight="1">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />

   <com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/ad"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="---------------------"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
   </LinearLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/header_height">

    <com.gains.myapp.KenBurnsView
        android:id="@+id/header_picture"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/picture0" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/header_logo"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/header_logo_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/header_logo_size"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_header_logo" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set your list view height to a value such that it covers 3/4th of thte screen . Try 400 , 450 dp.

Set property align parent bottom = true to your admob widget. This will stick your admob widget to the bottom

Comment: This is what I am doing. https://raw.github.com/flavienlaurent/NotBoringActionBar/master/graphics/notboringab.gif The area that the listview covers on the screen changes. And do I put the adview right after the listview?

Comment: User Relative Layout first of all. Then follow my steps.

Answer (score 0):

You have configured your ListView to consume all of the height of its parent leaving no room for anything else. I suggest you try something more like:

```
  <Linearayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/header_height">

        <com.gains.myapp.KenBurnsView
            android:id="@+id/header_picture"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/picture0" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/header_logo"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/header_logo_size"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/header_logo_size"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_header_logo" />

      </FrameLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
```

Note the **android:layout_weight="1"** in the ListView config. This will cause the ListView to expand to fill available space within its enclosing LinearLayout.

Read http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html
You need a better understanding of Android layouts, when to use what and how they work.

Comment: I get this hilarious error. Funniest thing i have read today.  This LinearLayout view is useless (no children, no background, no id, no style).

Comment: It sounds like you have closed off the LinearLayout element before describing it's children. You need to post what you have entered, because it can't be what I gave you.